# java compiler command line parameters "-parameters" doesn't work in intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

It works well before I add `org.thymeleaf.extras` in pom.xml. But after I do this, I can't get the params' name anymore. [debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgJC2.png) [error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3slzy.png) I had tried to delete the dependency but it doesn't work.

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.snake</groupId>
    <artifactId>qqzone</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>qqzone</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.8.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.14.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--  支持LocalDateTime      -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

[intellij java compiler setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hswOy.png)

DispatcherServlet

```java
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        // /hello. do -> hello -> helloController
        String servletPath = request.getServletPath().substring(1).split("\\.")[0];
        Object controllerBeanObj = beanFactory.getBean(servletPath);

        String operate = request.getParameter("operate");
        if (StringUtil.isEmpty(operate)) {
            operate = "index";
        }

        try {
            for (Method m : controllerBeanObj.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
                if (operate.equals(m.getName())) {

                    // 获取参数 
                    Parameter[] parameters = m.getParameters();
                    Object[] paramVals = new Object[parameters.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < paramVals.length; i++) {
                        Parameter param = parameters[i];
                        // -parameters doesn't work!!!
                        String paramName = param.getName();
                        if ("request".equals(paramName)) {
                            paramVals[i] = request;
                        } else if ("response".equals(paramName)) {
                            paramVals[i] = response;
                        } else if ("session".equals(paramName)) {
                            paramVals[i] = request.getSession();
                        } else {
                            String paramVal = request.getParameter(paramName);
                            if (paramVal != null && "java.lang.Integer".equals(param.getType().getName())) {
                                //!!!: argument type mismatch "2" != 2
                                paramVals[i] = Integer.parseInt(paramVal);
                            } else {
                                paramVals[i] = paramVal;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    Object retObj = m.invoke(controllerBeanObj, paramVals);

                    // 视图处理
                    String retStr = (String) retObj;
                    if (retStr.startsWith("redirect:")) {
                        String redirectStr = retStr.substring("redirect:".length());
                        response.sendRedirect(redirectStr);
                    } else {
                        processTemplate(retStr, request, response);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new DispatcherServletException();
        }
    }
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: Where is line 74 of `DispatcherServlet`?

Comment: And I don't see any relationship between your code and the command line.

Comment: remove modules from "override parameters per module" list of compiler settings in IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Try also adding parameters as a maven option, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-129794

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov It works again after I remove modules from `Per-module bytecode version` and `override parameters per module`. But it weird that I had tried this before but it didn't work.